# Openstreetmap Overlay Osmdroid example

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am looking at the SampleWithTilesOverlayAndCustomTileSource example in the osmdroid pack and I am wondering where the overlay is coming from/what format the overlay openfietskaart-rcn is - is it Openlayers/a WMS service and how can I make my own custom overlay working for this example? Would it work with GeoServer? I was not able to find tutorials on this example and hope someone can give me a hint on how to create my own layer, based on a .kml file for example. Thanks!

```
    this.mCustomTileSource = new XYTileSource("FietsRegionaal", null, 3, 18, 256, ".png",
        "http://overlay.openstreetmap.nl/openfietskaart-rcn/");
```

example here:
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/samples/SampleWithTilesOverlayAndCustomTileSource.java?r=829

Answer (score 1):

The custom tile source doesn't specify a custom URL scheme, so you can assume it uses the default implementation - a folder structure of PNG files starting at the base URL above, followed by zoom/X/Y.png.  The numbering matches Google Maps system.  Each PNG is 256 pixels square.  You can create a custom set of tiles using Mobile Atlas Creator (MOBAC), or I used a library called "mapnik" to convert KMLs to tiles.  The tiles could also come from your sdcard.

Here's a good site to show how the tiles are numbered:
http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

MOBAC:
http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

Mapnik:
http://mapnik.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When using Mobile Atlas Creator what "desired atlas format" do I need to choose?

Comment: You can use any of the 3 Osmdroid options.  A few notes...  When I've used zips created with MOBAC, I've had to crack open the zip and rename the top level folder to match the first parameter of your XYTileSource constructor.  By default MOBAC uses the tile source name, which is not always correct.  When using built-in tile sources like MapQuest, you can find the correct folder name in the Osmdroid source code, in TileSourceFactory.java.  For example, MapQuest had to be renamed to MapquestOSM.  Split large zips into multiple zips with one or more zoom levels each.  Glad I could help!